# Crystal Reports randomly asks for SQL login Details

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 Express. I have created my reports using Crystal Reports.

Whenever I need to view the report, I am randomly required to enter login details. I do not know how to overcome this.

All help is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
        Dim rptViewer As New rptAccidentClaim

        ' display CompanyName and footer  on Report
        Dim crCompa As Object
        Dim crFoote As Object
        crCompa = rptViewer.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("crCompany")
        crCompa.Text = g_Company
        crFoote = rptViewer.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("crFooterLine")
        crFoote.Text = g_FooterLine

        ' display Recipient Address on Report
        Dim crRecAddr1 As Object
        Dim crRecAddr2 As Object
        Dim crRecAddr3 As Object
        Dim crRecAddr4 As Object
        Dim crRecAddr5 As Object
        Dim crRecAddr6 As Object
        crRecAddr1 = rptViewer.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("crAddressLine1")
        crRecAddr1.Text = g_AddressLine1
        crRecAddr2 = rptViewer.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("crAddressLine2")
        crRecAddr2.Text = g_AddressLine2
        crRecAddr3 = rptViewer.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("crAddressLine3")
        crRecAddr3.Text = g_AddressLine3
        crRecAddr4 = rptViewer.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("crAddressLine4")
        crRecAddr4.Text = g_AddressLine4
        crRecAddr5 = rptViewer.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("crAddressLine5")
        crRecAddr5.Text = g_AddressLine5
        crRecAddr6 = rptViewer.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("crAddressLine6")
        crRecAddr6.Text = g_AddressLine6

        ' Set Database Logon Details 
        rptViewer.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "(password)", "MAIN-PC", "(databasename)")
        'Pass filter Paramter
        rptViewer.SetParameterValue("theID", m_theID)
        crvAccidentClaim.ReportSource = rptViewer
```

Answer (score -1):

hi we have the same problem..after searching for a lot of solution. i've noticed, one video on youtube that he cleared the attached report in crystal report viewer.
and then attach the report file(.rpt) manually in code. now there's no prompting message in my program asking for user login. i hope you understand and i hope it will help you xD